Web3 python websocket persistent connection
I am implementing a crypto payment system for my django web app. I have a smart contract that exposes some functions that let users purchase credits for my application by sending crypto to the smart contract. When a user calls one of these functions, an event containing the user id and the amount of credits purchased is logged by the contract.
Now I am trying to setup a persistent rpc websocket connection from my backend in order to catch all these events and update user credits accordingly.
These are my smart contranct's events:
event EthPurchase(uint256 indexed userId, uint256 amountWei, uint256 creditsPurchased, uint256 when);

event UsdtPurchase(uint256 indexed userId, uint256 amountUsdt, uint256 creditsPurchased, uint256 when);

this is my Python function that should catch and handle events:
async def subscribe_to_purchase_events(self):

        backoff = 1

        while True:
            try:
                w3 = await AsyncWeb3(
                    WebSocketProvider(
                        ETHEREUM_LOCALNET_WS_PROVIDER,
                        request_timeout=None,
                        subscription_response_queue_size=100000,
                        silence_listener_task_exceptions=False,
                    ),
                )
                w3.middleware_onion.inject(
                    web3.middleware.ExtraDataToPOAMiddleware,
                    layer=0,
                )
                eth_purchase_event_topic = w3.keccak(
                    text="EthPurchase(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)",
                )
                usdt_purchase_event_topic = w3.keccak(
                    text="UsdtPurchase(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)",
                )

                filter_params = {
                    "address": VAULT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
                    "topics": [
                        [eth_purchase_event_topic, usdt_purchase_event_topic],
                    ],
                }

                subscription_id = await w3.eth.subscribe("logs", filter_params)

                backoff = 1

                async for payload in w3.socket.process_subscriptions():
                    result = payload["result"]

                    user_id = decode(["uint256"], result["topics"][1])[0]
                    _, credits_purchased, _ = decode(
                        ["uint256", "uint256", "uint256"],
                        result["data"],)

                    await self.handle_purchase_event(user_id, credits_purchased) #this is the helper function that adds credits to the user in response to event logs

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in purchase events subscription: {e}")
                await asyncio.sleep(backoff)
                backoff = min(backoff * 1.5, 30)

`
I am having trouble in keeping the subscription constantly catching and processing events.
When I run the subscribe_to_purchase_events function (using a dedicated service in a docker container), for some time everything works as expected: events logged by my smart contract are correctly catched and processed. After some time though, it stops working without raising any exception.
I think the execution gets stuck in the async for payload in w3.socket.process_subscriptions(): line, because for some reason no events are being added to my subscription's queue. Again, this only happens after some time, at the beginning everything works fine.
I am currently testing this system with my contract deployed to a local Hardhat node that forks Ethereum mainnet.
Any idea what the reason could be and how can I fix this?
